# Как запустить helloworld на C с помощью Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Как запустить самую обычную программу hello world на VS Code минимумом действий? 
Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, ибо до этого пользовался либо сайтом *repl.it*, в котором всего одна кнопка Run, запускающая программу, либо всякими IDE. Скачал на винду компилятор *mingw* и прописал пути в переменных средах. Научился компилировать файл через терминал с помощью: cd/*директория файла* и gcc helloworld.c. Таким образом компилируется код и создается exe-шник. Запуская exe-шник выходит вывод программы.
Можно ли проделать это (скомпилировать и сразу запустить программу) в VS Code лишь какой-нибудь горячей клавишой(как в IDE-шках)? Установленные плагины в VS Code: C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing, Code Runner.

Comment: Конкретно C++ не запускал. Но подход везде одинаковый [helloworldcpp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp), да и в документации все разжевано лучше некуда. Запускается кнопкой или клавишей F5.

Comment: [Ссылка](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). Тут для C++ (кому нужен си в 2020 г.? :( ), но, думаю, вы поймёте.

Comment: "Научился компилировать файл через терминал" - ну так и делайте. Но лучше используйте полноценную Visual Studio.